# Remove text before and after a word in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have somethinghs like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Jake', 'Nate', 'Max', 'Alex', 'Lex', 'Kat', 'Nate', 'Jake'],
                'textBefore F1: textAfter' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                'textBefore F2: textAfter' : [8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1],
                'textBefore F3: textAfter' : [9, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5],
                'Color' : ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'balck', 'purple', 'pink', 'orange', 'green'],})
```

I would like to rename only the columns that contain the 'F'. And I would like to keep the number that follows the F.
For example:

```
textBefore F1: textAfter
```

he should become alone

```
F1
```

Of course for each line that contains the F. How could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets use `index.str.replace`

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(r'.*\b(F\d+)\b.*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

##### Result

```
   Name  F1  F2  F3   Color
0  Jake   1   8   9     red
1  Nate   2   4   8    blue
2   Max   3   2   5  yellow
3  Alex   4   7   4   balck
4   Lex   5   9   6  purple
5   Kat   6   6   3    pink
6  Nate   7   5   2  orange
7  Jake   8   1   5   green
```

Comment: A thousand thanks!

Comment: Cool solution!  
The best I was able to do was:
```df1.rename(columns={col: match[0] for col in df1.columns if (match := re.search("F\d+", col))})```